# racket: manipulating jpeg files

Tags: racket, jpeg, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I'm trying to manipulate jpeg files in racket lang. I failed to find any racket library with good cross-platform support (linux, mac osx, win10). Does exist any?

Actions I want to perform are read exif, scale images and store it to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [several](https://github.com/wingo/racket-jpeg) [external](https://github.com/videolang/video) [libraries](https://github.com/lehitoskin/png-image/tree/master) that you can use to do image (and video) manipulation. However Racket actually comes bundled with a good amount of image manipulation tools (that work on jpg, png, bitmap, etc.). Most notably the [`pict`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/index.html?q=pict) library and the [`racket/draw`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sql/index.html?q=sql) library. I highly recommend you use those for most standard image manipulation tasks (e.g. scaling, transformations, etc.). You can even use the [`sql`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sql/index.html?q=sql) library (which also comes with Racket to store your files to a database.

If you want to use the `racket/draw` class, you can create a [`bitmap%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html?q=bitmap%25) object which allows you to save to and load from files. You can also use a [`bitmap-dc%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap-dc_.html?q=bitmap%25) to do basic drawing operations.

The `pict` library is a nice functional API for image manipulation. And you can use the [`bitmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/Basic_Pict_Constructors.html?q=bitmap#%28def._%28%28lib._pict%2Fmain..rkt%29._bitmap%29%29) function to get a bitmap from a file, as well as convert a `bitmap%` object to a `pict` object. The `pict->bitmap` function lets you go the other way, converting a `pict` object to a `bitmap`.

[image: Racket Draw/Pict Example]

Comment: thx for hints. I prefer to store jpeg in sqlite database, with safe-file i would need to save it to file and then read back to application. Is there any way how to get jpeg-bytes? I found jpeg.rkt -- it looks like binding to libjpeg library, maybe I could some how use this.